# 'Check' not displayed on selected items from a p:selectManyMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the selectManyMenu widget from Primefaces 5.3 to display the list of roles users can have in each of our apps.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Roles:" rendered="#{controller.enabledApp[app.id] and not empty app.roles}"/>
<p:selectManyMenu converter="#{roleConverter}" var="r" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true"
  rendered="#{controller.enabledApp[app.id] and not empty app.roles}" value="#{app.selectedRoles}">

    <f:selectItems value="#{app.roles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role}"/>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{r.name}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

The problem is, when I preload these roles from the database, populating the selectedRoles field of the app entity, Primefaces adds the ui-state-highlight CSS class to the table rows used to represent these selected roles, but it doesn't add the ui-state-active to the div that represents the checkbox.

This is what I get:

```
<tr class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" style="">
  <td>
    <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
      <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>Admin</td>
</tr>
```

And this is what I should get:

```
<tr class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" style="">
  <td>
    <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
      <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-check"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>Admin</td>
</tr>
```

I could just change the CSS to display a checked checkbox when the parent tr has the ui-state-highlight class, but I'd much rather solve the problem.

Can this be a bug in Primefaces? Do I have some error that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version, PrimeFaces 5.3

Comment: Checked the PF source for this behaviour?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem,  I see this hasn't been answered in over 4 years.